# json_encode returns 200 and undefined

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, wordpress

I'd like to have a code to add or remove from database bookmarks.
The code is ready and it adds and removes from database bookmarks correctly, but when I call the function it keeps returning the `json error` instead `json success` even if the code works.

I'd like to know what's wrong with the code (that I got and adapt from somewhere else) because the client side is not receiving the correct values `true` or `false`, it only triggers the `json beforeSending` and `json error`.

server side:

```
if($isFavorite) {
    // if it's favorite, remove from bookmarks
    return json_encode(array("status" => true, "added" => false));
} else {
    // if it's not favorite, include into bookmarks
    return json_encode(array("status" => false, "added" => true));
}
```

client side:

```
<script>
    function addItemToUsersList(userId, type, itemId) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            'url': 'xxx', 
            'type': 'GET',
            'dataType': 'json', 
            'data': {userid: userId, type: type, itemid: itemId}, 
            'success': function(data)  {
                console.log('json success');
            },
            'beforeSend': function() {
                console.log('json beforeSending');
            },
            'error': function(data) {
                console.log('json error');
                console.log(data.status + ' ' + data.added);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

The `console.log(data.status + ' ' + data.added);` line logs `200 undefined`

How may I return the correct values `true` or `false` for both `"status"` and `"added"`?

---

Edit:
The `json success` is never logged on console, so I don't know what happened on server side. I need to know this because I need to change the class of an element to display an empty or yellow star.

Comment: Are you sure you really send the output to the client somewhere.

Comment: It's been a while since I worked with PHP but aren't you supposed to echo out the JSON? `echo json_encode(...)`.

Comment: Send them as integers and treat them on return. Boolean values are problematic to send.

Comment: The `json success` is never logged on console, so I don't know what happened on server side. I need to know this because I need to change the class of an element to display an empty or yellow star.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are `return`ing the result and not doing anything with that return elsewhere, you will not get any response to your ajax call, so it's `undefined`. As @MikeC says, you must `echo` it at some point.

If you are not already echoing it elsewhere, try:

```
$response = array(
    'status' => $isFavourite,
    'added' => !$isFavourite
);
echo json_encode($response);
```

My suggestion is also if 'status' and 'added' are really just the opposite of each other every time, then you probably only need to send 'status' on its own. In your JS you can just check 'status' and reverse the boolean as I've done above, if you want to know what the value of `added` would be.

```
 var added = !data.status;
```

---

**Update**

If your ajax request is coming back to the `error` function, the request itself is probably failing.

Change your error function to this, to debug what has happened:

```
'error': function(jqXHR, status, error) {
    console.log(status);
    console.log(error);
}
```

You might have an error in server-side code somewhere or you're calling the wrong PHP script perhaps?

Comment: But what I need to get is that the function was an success and what happened in there, if the bookmark was added or removed. I just gave an example what I was getting from server side.

Comment: @William I understand but are you echoing the `json_encode()` somewhere in the PHP? You understand that `return json_encode()` on its own will not send anything back from the server side to the JS?

Comment: Ok got it, I changed the `return` to `echo` and changed `array("status" => false, "added" => true)` to `"status" => true`, but still I get only the number 200 calling `console.log(data)`.

Comment: I'll try your last update to see what's going on, but I can assure that any of the PHP code is working properly, because I can `insert` and `delete` from mySQL table with the PHP code, I checked that, I just don't know why I get the error..

Comment: with your last update I got:
`parsererror`
`SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0(…)`

Comment: OK it likely means your server is actually returning HTML because of some error you have there, it's not returning JSON like you think.  Try in your error function adding `console.log(jqXHR.responseText)` and see what it says. Double check you have no errors in your PHP script (like, try running your PHP script on its own to check it works).

Comment: Alright, I'll do that. I runned the PHP by itself before trying the JSON and it works. It adds the data to MySQL table and removes it if it's already there. I'll post the result in a minute.

Comment: It logged: `<!-- Really Simple SSL mixed content fixer active -->`

Comment: Now I'm getting `bookmark: 0 or 1 got from PHP`: `{"bookmark":1}<!-- Really Simple SSL mixed content fixer active -->`

Comment: @William OK, after your `echo json_encode` line in the PHP, what happens if you add `die();`?

Comment: Same result with `die();`

Comment: It seems a issue with one of the WordPress plugins: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/non-json-content-breaks-javascript-resulting-in-syntax-error?replies=8

Comment: That's it, the plugin `Really Simple SSL` is making the code to go to `error`, I disabled it and it returned me `json success`. I'll try to check on it but do you have any solutions? Like trim the `bookmark`.

Comment: I've created a new question for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37331802/wordpress-plugin-really-simple-ssl-json-returning-error Thanks bro